# How can I make the protagonist from the Night Angel Trilogy into a PC?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, dnd-3.5e, character-creation

I'm a big fan of Brent Weeks's [Night Angel Trilogy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Night_Angel_Trilogy) of novels and want to play a PC as close as possible to the wetboy [Kylar Stern/Durzo Blint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_The_Night_Angel_Trilogy_characters#Azoth), a rogue, assassin, and warrior with the awesome talents.

The [wetboy](http://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/Wetboy_%283.5e_Prestige_Class%29) is a homebrew prestige class for *Dungeons and Dragons 3.5*, and since that's already written I *could* turn that into a base class for *Pathfinder*, but I'm not sure how.

Using homebrew or official sources, how can I make a PC as close as possible to the books' protagonist?

Comment: This is possibly answerable if you make it clear what, exactly, about the prestige class interests you as, then, both official and unofficial recommendations can be offered. Is it just that the class is dark, dangerous, and kills with an attitude (i.e. fluff), or is it, like, the weird talents thing it's got going (i.e. the crunch) that pops for you?

Comment: You appear to have accidentally created more than one account. You will be unable to comment on or accept answers to your own question until you [merge your accounts using the instructions in the help centre](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts).

Comment: Closed as too broad - this is pulling answers ranging from "guesses on builds you might like" to "conversions of the homebrew class you linked" with no real way to tell which of these things actually solves your problem at all.  Please provide more behind what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that I could properly emulate your fanboy dreams, but I can come close. The Closest class that I am familiar with as far as *Pathfinder* goes it the [**Witch**](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/witch) class. The Witch has many staples that Kylar Stern possess, mainly the non-human, sapient companion and the knack for stealth that the Wetboy class you have procured possesses. When you first create your character, you canonically bond with an animal. This creature grants you certain bonuses as well as acts as a battle companion/spellbook. The Patron, however, is a vague, astral benefactor that teaches you spells related to its theme on top of the spells that you learn from your familiar. I have no idea what a ka'kari is (though I imagine some sort of Draconic Goat), It is possible to upgrade your familiar into a more formidable creature with the "Improved Familiar" or "Evolved Familiar" Feats. The themes that Patrons can possess are myriad, so virtually no single witch is exactly the same. Both of these things can grant you improved stealth and stealthy spells. Plus fire
.

One of the greatest benefits of taking a Witch as your character would be the **Hex** abilities that you learn. You start with one of these Gnome-like spell abilities, some with minor effects and unlimited uses, others with incredible power and very restricted in its casting/use. Of these 67 abilities, the one that could prove beneficial to your character's story would be the **Coven** hex. It allows you to become indoctrinated into a Hag's Coven (minimum 1 Hag), and grant circumstance bonuses to witches that share this feat. What makes this so essential to your character is the one ability that the source inspiration has that a witch cannot perform on their own: resurrection.

Of the spells and hexes that any witch can learn, ergo any Hag, there are a grand total of two spells that grant the power of specifically reversing death. The drawback, however, is that these spells either take a tremendous amount materials or apply negative levels to the target, not to mention that these are among the last spells that any character can learn. So, with a coven connection, you could have made a deal with the coven's Hag (or your parents work too) to use the most powerful resurrection spell on you PLUS the added bonus of removing any nasty side effects, for some unspecified price. Though you *might* have to talk to your DM first about it...

TLDR: Be a witch. Customize your Familiar. Get Coven Hex. Get revived constantly while Matrihag eats your friends.

Answer (score -1):

I can't give an answer like Areadbhair due to my lack of knowledge in the novel but the wetboy prestige class looks interesting and worth taking with some backgrounds unrelated to the novel (hmm, maybe a ninja crossed with arcane trickster), so I'll convert it to pathfinder for you. In fact, I might use this instead of my normal 20 levels into a full caster class.

---

Things changed: Converted numbers like save progression into their Pathfinder equivalents. Talents look like Ki, sound like Ki, and feel like Ki so I'm going to simplify it into Ki. Shadow meld and Disguise master are now SLA. Poison making is turned into a bonus to rolls rather than a decreased DC (experience makes you better at challenges, it doesn't make a challenge inherently easier...). Also, the requirement says "mobility" which has dodge as a prerequisite then gives you dodge as a bonus feat. I removed speed boost for expeditious retreat as a talent. Weapon master + legend seemed OP with a +5 bonus but I got lazy

---

Skills: Swim 6 ranks, Stealth 4 ranks, Disguise 5 ranks, Acrobatics 6 ranks

Feats: Dodge

Special: Must defeat water elemental without taking damage

Must have 3 dice (+3d6) sneak attack damage

---

Hit Dice: d8

The wetboy's class skills (and the key ability for each skill) are Acrobatics (Dex), Bluff (Cha), Climb (Str), Diplomacy (Cha), Disable Device (Dex), Disguise (Cha), Escape Artist (Dex), Intimidate (Cha), Linguistics (Int), Perception (Wis), Sense Motive (Wis), Sleight of Hand (Dex), Stealth (Dex), Swim (Str), and Use Magic Device (Cha).

Skills gained per level: 4 + int modifier

```
Level   BAB   Fort   Ref   Will   Special
1st     +0    +0     +1    +0     Sneak attack +1d6, cantrips & 1st level ki, Mobility, QuickDraw, Poison Expertise, Weapon hiding, Silver tongue
2nd     +1    +1     +1    +1
3rd     +2    +1     +2    +1     Sneak attack +2d6, Shadow Meld 1/day
4th     +3    +1     +2    +1     2nd & 3rd level ki
5th     +3    +2     +3    +2     Sneak attack +3d6, Master of Disguise
6th     +4    +2     +3    +2     Shadow Meld 2/day
7th     +5    +2     +4    +2     Sneak attack +4d6, 4th & 5th level ki
8th     +6    +3     +4    +3
9th     +6    +3     +5    +3     Sneak attack +5d6, Shadow Meld 3/day
10th    +7    +3     +5    +3     6th level ki, Legend
```

Weapon and Armor Proficiency: Wetboys are proficient with all simple weapons and a martial weapon of his own choice, along with shuriken, light shields, and armour.

Sneak Attack:
This is exactly like the rogue ability of the same name. The extra damage dealt increases by +1d6 every other level (1st, 3rd, 5th, 7th, and 9th). If an wetboy gets a sneak attack bonus from another source, the bonuses on damage stack.

Ki: A wetboy has the ability to use magic through the manifestation of power in his own body called Ki, which is refilled upon resting for 8 hours. His Ki is equal to half his class level plus his Cha modifier. The spells the Wetboy can use are pulled from the Sorceror/Wizard spell list, the point cost is equal to the 1 + spell level. These spells do not provoke attacks of opportunity and are treated as spell like abilities. He can only cast cantrips and 1st level spells at level 1, 2nd and 3rd spells at level 4, 4th and 5th spells at level 7, and 6th level spells at level 10. Treat his class level as his caster level, and he cannot cast spells with harmless effects on others.

```
cantrips  - Detect Poison, Detect Magic, Read Magic, Daze, Light, Prestidigitation. 
1st level - Color Spray, Magic Aura, Ventriloquism, Sleep, Expeditious Retreat. 
2nd level - Obscure Object, Glitterdust, Invisibility, Mirror Image, Misdirection, Phantom Trap, Bear's Endurance, Bull's Strength, Cat's Grace, Eagle's Splendor, Fox's Cunning, Owl's Wisdom, Spider Climb. 
3rd level - Dispel Magic, Nondetection, Displacement, Illusory Script, Major Image, Haste. 
4th level - Greater Invisibility. 
5th level - False Vision, Persistent Image. 
6th level - Mislead, Shadow Walk.
```

Mobility: Wetboy gains mobility as a bonus feat

Quickdraw: Wetboy gains quickdraw as a bonus feat

Poison Use: Wetboy cannot accidentally poison himself.

Poison Expertise, Weapon hiding & Silver tongue: Wetboy is proficient at making poison and gains a bonus to alchemy checks to make poison, perception checks to identify poison and sleight of hand checks to apply poison equal to half his class level. He also gains a bonus to sleight of hand checks to hide weapons equal to half his class level. Finally, he gets a bonus to bluff, intimidation and diplomacy checks made to avoid combat or trouble equal to half his class level.

Shadow Meld: At level 3 and every 3 levels onwards, Wetboy gains a use of shadow meld per day. He can expend a use of Shadow Meld to cast Shadow Step as an immediate action

Master of Disguise: At level 5, by spending 3 ki points and a minute, Wetboy can change his appearance as per the spell alter self for the rest of the day. By spending 1 ki point and a swift action, he may either change his original conditions, or alter his appearance to a specific individual as per the spell disguise self.

Legend: At level 10, Wetboy gains +2 to all attack rolls and cha based skill checks.

---

If all else fails, go arcane trickster or veiled illusionist. Maybe even Psionics can help you, as Talents look like some variation of spell points.

Answer (score -1):

Kylar Stern (Durzo Blint is an epic leveled character pretending to be a nearly-epic assassin - not exactly the best material to try to copy in 3.5/PF) is a decent assassin but his true power comes when he learns to use magic - power that absolutely dwarfs his previous abilities.

Given his various feats in the books, probably the closest you're going to come to his abilities as a PF character is a single level in rogue (or better, Unchained rogue), largely to get the skills, and then after that levels in Wizard or Sorcerer.  The Arcane spell list has all the things he uses (invisibility, spider climbing, dispel magic, strength/dex buffs, teleportation you can fluff as room-crossing backflips, alter self/disguise self etc), and trying to mix in too much rogue will delay the spell progression so much as to be useless at any level where such tricks could be impressive - because keep in mind, Kylar Stern seems so cool partially because in his world, his tricks are extremely impressive to those around him - if you're lagging behind ECL in PF when those tricks come online, it's not impressive to anyone.

Another possible way to represent Kylar Stern would be to use the Synthesist archetype of the Summoner class.  It grants a bunch of bonuses to physical action while synthed that could be fluffed as the Night Angel form, and offers a decent set of spells on it's list for being the Night Angel.

A third option would be to play a Vivisectionist alchemist.  Sneak attack progression, poison use, and spells via extracts such as invisibility, alter form, etc.  The Mutagen changes could be the Night Angel form, in this case.

Both the Synthesist Summoner and the Vivisectionist Alchemist's magic are not as impressive as the Wizard or Sorcerer, making that key part of Kylar Stern's characterization - when he powers up and becomes a wetboy/the Night Angel - less impactful overall, but could work in a game without tier-1 casters.

A very carefully built Magus might be able to pull off a Kylar Stern, but it would be somewhat hard to sell, as while Magus gets the whole 'good at swordfighting' aspect of Kylar stern, it lags hard on the 'good at stealth/disguise/poisons' and 'amazing magic' facets.